# Using a div as a link - option to open new tab?

Tags: javascript, redirect, html

Currently I'm using this small piece of js in my site to allow my div to act as a button:

```
<div id="item" onclick="location.href='http://www.google.com';" style="cursor:pointer;">Google</div>
```

But something I do very often when web browsing is opening a large amount of tabs. Is there any way I could modify my code to allow for this?

Comment: plz visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:-

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .sampleDiv
    {
            position:relative;
            margin:0px auto;
            width:400px;
            height:200px;
            background-color:#CCCCCC;
            text-align:center;
    }
    .actualLink
    {
            position:absolute;
            top:0px;
            left:0px;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
    }
    .linkText
    {
            position:relative;
            top:80px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div class="sampleDiv">
                    <a class="linkText" href="test.html">testing</a>
                    <a class="actualLink" href="test.html"></a>
            </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The link with class actualLink is covering whole of the div.
The link with class linkText is providing the text.
The purpose of using two  tag is that if you only use actualLink then you cannot position the text wherever you want.By using the link with class linkText you have flexibility of centering(vertically) the text(horizontal centering can be done using only actualLink)

Answer (score 3):

My solution was to replace the div blocks with anchor blocks.  Anchor blocks can now take on the CSS styles of nearly anything a div can do, but it can also include href, which the browser will recognize and give you the right-click options you want to see.

So old:

```
<div class="divClass" onClick="location.href='http://www.google.com'">asdf</div>
```

becomes

```
<a class="divClass" href="http://www.google.com">asdf</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly do this, as it's a user setting on their browser whether windows open as new windows or as tabs.

There is `target="_newtab"` but that isn't widely supported.

So in the onclick:

```
window.open('page.html','_newtab');
```

But attempting to override a users browser preference isn't a good idea IMO.

To do it on a right click something like:

```
$('#item').mousedown(function(event) {
  if(event.which == 3) { // right click
      window.open('page.html','_newtab');
  }
})
```

Comment: I was hoping for the right click dialog as an option, not new tab all the time.

Answer (score 1):

you could do:

```
onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com', somename);" ...
```

do you mean, something like:

```
..onmousedown="op(your_url,event);"..

function op(url,event) {
  if (event.button == 2) {
    window.open(url);
  }
}
```

Comment: I was more looking for the right click -> open in new tab to be available rather than new tab all the time.

Comment: So would that open a new tab when I right click? That's sort of what I want, yeah. You know when yo right click on a link how it shows options of how to open that? That's what I want the div to do, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

use target="_blank"

Have a look here

Document : [HTML `<a>` target Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) 
Demo : [Try It](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_target)

Comment: I was thinking of the dialog that pops up when you right click. I wanted that to be present.

Comment: can u give us any live example. link of any site where this is happening.

Comment: I don't really have one. It's just that I want to use the right click link dialog when I right click my div.

Comment: Your hyperlink is not working. Error: `The file you asked for does not exist.`

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no cross-browser way to do this.
Forms or window.open will open a new window, not a new tab.
And don't try to create a link in memory and click it with javascript because chrome won't open the new tab, as a security feature.