# How do I make a div link open in a new tab Javascript onClick="window.location

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a range of social media buttons which when the mouse hovers it switches to a different image (giving it a highlight effect). The images work as I want them to, however, I can't seem to figure out how to load the page into a new tab/screen. I need to implement the equivalent of .

Assuming I have to change something in the onClick.... ?

Here is code:

```
<div id="insidefooter">
<ul>
    <li>
        <div id="facebook" style="cursor:pointer;" onClick="window.location='https://www.facebook.com';"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div id="youtube" style="cursor:pointer;" onClick="window.location='https://www.youtube.com';"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div id="twitter" style="cursor:pointer;" onClick="window.location='https://twitter.com/';"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here is CSS:

```
#facebook {
height: 40px;
position: relative;
top: 0px;
left: 260px;
width: 40px;
background-image:url(/img/index/footer/facebook-button.jpg);
}

#facebook:hover {
height: 40px;
width: 40px;
background-image:url(/img/index/footer/facebook-button2.jpg);
top: 0;
left: 260px;
width: 40px;
position: relative;
}

#youtube {
height: 40px;
position: relative;
top: -62px;
left: 360px;
width: 40px;
background-image:url(/img/index/footer/youtube-button.jpg);
}

#youtube:hover {
height: 40px;
width: 40px;
background-image:url(/img/index/footer/youtube-button2.jpg);
top: -62px;
left: 360px;
width: 40px;
position: relative;
```

I left out some CSS code to make it simpler, but here is a demo http://fiddle.jshell.net/3Bsyd/2/

Thank you!

Comment: `window.open();` ? If you don't define the height and width it will open in a new tab.

Comment: you can find here duplicate..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529837/using-a-div-as-a-link-option-to-open-new-tab

Comment: @rkrk thanks, sorry must have missed question.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`onclick="window.open('http://google.pl', '_blank');"`

Comment: I am looking for the right click option that I need the user to decide whether opens the link in new tab or in current tab. Same as pressing `Ctrl` + Click can open in new tab while clicking opens the page in current tab.

Answer (score 2):

`<div id="facebook" style="cursor:pointer;" onClick="window.open('http://www.google.com','_newtab');">Test</div>`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What's the difference between _newtab and _blank?

Comment: Both do same operation _blank is advisable

Comment: whats the difference? @ ben_dchost